# Should an unseen character be presumed alive, or dead?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I'm cataloguing all the characters in A Song of Ice and Fire, and am currently working out each of their status as dead or alive. Some characters are (spoilers AGOT)

> missing and presumed dead, such as Benjen Stark, lost beyond the Wall. For those characters I would just say "Unknown"

Other characters you would think have died, but are still alive, such as (spoilers ACOK)

> Kyra, Bandy, Palla, Turnip, Old Nan, and certain other residents of Winterfell, who didn't die in the Sack, but were taken prisoner by the Boltons. We only know about this because they're explicitly mentioned in the appendix.

What about minor characters who get no other mention in any canon source? For example, Lew and Donnis are two guards at Winterfell, mentioned in the beginning of AGOT (more spoilers ACOK)

> Should I presume that Lew and Donnis are dead because Winterfell was sacked, and they haven't been explicitly mentioned? Should I presume that they are alive because there's no information to suggest that they've died? Or is their fate best marked as "Unknown"?

Essentially, what is the default position for whether a character is alive?

Comment: "Should an unseen character be presumed alive or dead?" No.

Comment: Fixed the title.

Comment: The comma doesn't change the verity of Kevin's comment...

Comment: Well, I wasn't asking a binary question. If Kevin thinks that I shouldn't make any assumptions and should label all characters who I don't know for sure to be alive or dead as "unknown", then he could say so explicitly.

Comment: There's also the possibility of someone being dead and still being an active character.

Comment: Is this question asking if there is a rule-of-thumb for determining items not outlined in text? As far as the reader is concerned all unmentioned characters are Schrodinger's cat.

Comment: @Gorchestopher H - Okay, but what if you had opened the box a while ago and discovered it was alive, then the box closes and you don't hear from the cat for a long time? Do you call the cat alive until you have reason to suspect otherwise (sack of Winterfell etc) return to uncertainty, or call it dead as soon as you've a reasonable suspicion?

Comment: And yeah, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @LeoKing Regardless of how many times the cat is noticed to be alive, if it goes in the box alive, it's both. Often readers are led to incorrectly assume some likely conclusion that is false. For what context is the purpose of your "default alive-ness"?

Comment: Can you explain that question a little better?

Comment: @LeoKing GorchestopherH means, what are you going to use this knowledge for? Schrödinger and his cruel games aside, what would it gain you to be able to presume that, say, everybody is still alive but they just won't be heard from again?

Comment: It's not a question of gain, but of default assumptions. For my purposes, I need to be able to determine whether a character is alive or dead. If I don't have any information at all, should I go either way, or make an indeterminate judgement? If I have information to *suggest* a character's death, should I presume dead until given alternative reason?

Comment: The purposes in question: I'm compiling a spreadsheet of every single character in ASOIAF, and now I want to record information of personal interest about those characters. So all I "gain" is interest, in knowing how many characters are dead or alive or unknown.

Comment: You may be interested in this [Missing Persons thread](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/123757-the-back-of-a-westeros-milk-carton/?p=6665456) on Westeros.org

Answer (score 3):

As a general rule if a character's death is not confirmed, it would probably be best to classify them as **Presumed Dead** or **Missing, presumed dead**. Quite a few characters fall into this designation, including Benjen, Syrio, Tyrek Lannister, and most minor characters from Winterfell. I hope we get as much closure as possible over the next books, but I suspect that most of these presumed deaths will not be confirmed one way or the other by the end of the series.

As a final reference, you may also want to check each book's appendix for these characters, to see if their status is listed.

Comment: I'm checking the AWOIAF pages, just because it's a little quicker. But good idea.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you should add the same status as Benjen's -- **unknown**. Since we don't know what happened to him or some other minor characters, we can only guess their fate. Some of the characters' fate (surely the main characters) would most likely be revealed in future books, but the fate of some other minors might be left unknown, even at the end of the series.

That is the reason why there are some [theories](https://www.google.gr/search?q=Benjen&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs&gfe_rd=cr&ei=aw4CVM2bNcWF8Qf50IGADg#channel=rcs&q=benjen+stark+theories&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official) about Benjen.